# SplitViewController Opening Other Views in Xcode 4.2 with NSNotifications

Tags: xcode, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, nsnotifications

I am trying to make a Split View Controller app and was following a recipe tutorial. However the tutorial is from before Xcode 4.2 and will not properly work. I have looked everywhere for a simple tutorial for Xcode 4.2 and story boards but could not find any. Anyways below is my code and my error any help will be greatly appreciated!

Error:

```
2012-01-02 16:37:40.061 blackdahlia[2233:f803] -[DetailViewController recieveNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c35650
2012-01-02 16:37:40.063 blackdahlia[2233:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController recieveNotification]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6c35650'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x13be052 0x154fd0a 0x13bfced 0x1324f00 0x1324ce2 0x9c9a39 0x1389885 0x13897a8 0x90e1aa 0x91ab13 0x334b 0xa571d 0xa5952 0x92d86d 0x1392966 0x1392407 0x12f57c0 0x12f4db4 0x12f4ccb 0x12a7879 0x12a793e 0x15a9b 0x2688 0x25e5 0x1)
terminate called throwing an exception
```

MasterViewController.m

```
#import "MasterViewController.h"

#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation MasterViewController

@synthesize detailViewController = _detailViewController;
@synthesize anotherdetailViewController;
@synthesize recipeArray, recipe;


- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
    self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(320.0, 600.0);
    [super awakeFromNib];

    recipeArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    recipe = [[Recipe alloc] init];

    recipe.name = @"Sex on the Beach";
    recipe.instructions = @"Sexy Instructions";
    recipe.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"testimage.jpg"];
    [recipeArray addObject:recipe];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [recipeArray count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    recipe = [recipeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = recipe.name;

    return cell;
}

- (void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    anotherdetailViewController.recipe = [recipeArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Test" object:self];
    NSLog(@"NOTIFICATION SENT");
}

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/

@end
```

DetailViewController.m

```
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@interface DetailViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController *masterPopoverController;
- (void)configureView;
@end

@implementation DetailViewController

@synthesize detailItem = _detailItem;
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel = _detailDescriptionLabel;
@synthesize masterPopoverController = _masterPopoverController;
@synthesize recipe, imageView;

#pragma mark - Managing the detail item

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }

    if (self.masterPopoverController != nil) {
        [self.masterPopoverController dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
    }        
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(recieveNotification) name:@"Test" object:nil];
}

- (void)recieveNotification:(NSNotification *) notification{

    if ([[notification name] isEqualToString:@"Test"]) {
        self.navigationItem.title = recipe.name;
        [self.imageView setImage:recipe.image];
        NSLog(@"Notification Recieved");
    }
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return YES;
}

#pragma mark - Split view

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController
{
    barButtonItem.title = NSLocalizedString(@"Master", @"Master");
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:barButtonItem animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = popoverController;
}

- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem
{
    // Called when the view is shown again in the split view, invalidating the button and popover controller.
    [self.navigationItem setLeftBarButtonItem:nil animated:YES];
    self.masterPopoverController = nil;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `-receiveNotification:` method takes an `NSNotification` as an argument, but you have specified the selector for the notification to be `-receiveNotification`.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(recieveNotification) name:@"Test" object:nil];
```

Note the lack of a colon. This means that the notification is actually looking for a method with the signature: `- (void)receiveNotification` instead of `- (void)receiveNotification:(NSNotification *)notification`.